# android emulator shows grey blank screen but the screen shots saved shows launcher

Tags: android-emulator

I am trying to run android emulator on macOS. It runs and boots but the screen is just blank, when i take a screenshot it shows the apps and launcher and when i click on some app it opens because when i screenshot it is opened
[Screenshot showing the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oA9DR.png)

1st image is how the emulator is displaying to me
2nd image is the screenshot on homepage
3rd image when i tap on the place where the icon it starts that app (screenshot still doesnt display anything on the emulator)

````
INFO    | Android emulator version 32.1.15.0 (build_id 10696886) (CL:N/A)
INFO    | Found systemPath /Users/work/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86/
INFO    | Found systemPath /Users/work/Library/Android/sdk/system-images/android-30/google_apis/x86/
INFO    | Storing crashdata in: /tmp/android-work/emu-crash.db, detection is enabled
INFO    | Duplicate loglines will be removed, if you wish to see each indiviudal line launch with the -log-nofilter flag.
WARNING | Please update the emulator to one that supports the feature(s): Vulkan
WARNING | Running on a system with less than 6 logical cores. Setting number of virtual cores to 1
WARNING | cannot add library /Users/work/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
INFO    | added library /Users/work/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
objc[4923]: Class WebSwapCGLLayer is implemented in both /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/WebCore.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/libANGLE-shared.dylib (0x7ffb4b67d038) and /Users/work/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle/libGLESv2.dylib (0x12ee3a748). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
WARNING | *** No gRPC protection active, consider launching with the -grpc-use-jwt flag.***
INFO    | Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local, auth: none
INFO    | Advertising in: /Users/work/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/avd/running/pid_4923.ini
INFO    | Setting display: 0 configuration to: 1080x2400, dpi: 420x420
ERROR   | Unable to connect to adb daemon on port: 5037
2023-10-25 01:04:32.054 qemu-system-x86_64[4923:59227] [CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] returning nil because device is nil.
2023-10-25 01:04:34.653 qemu-system-x86_64[4923:59227] [CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] returning nil because device is nil.
2023-10-25 01:04:34.711 qemu-system-x86_64[4923:59227] [CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] returning nil because device is nil.
2023-10-25 01:04:34.735 qemu-system-x86_64[4923:59227] [CAMetalLayer nextDrawable] returning nil because device is nil.```


I tried reinstalling android emulator deleted avd's and created again.
````